# Play several mp3 files in one Onclick statement?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm learning android and my first app is a simple music instrument. I have 7 buttons at the moment, and i'm using MediaPlayer for each one. The thing is that every button has the same functionality, and I want to avoid a switch statement on the Onclick method - wich is the only thing i find on the web. Someone told me to name the buttons with the correspondent mp3 file and write a simple "play" function that would match the right key/button, but I guess i'm not doing it right. Can someone help me out? Here's what i've got, and much apreciated for the help:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

   //these buttons have the same name as the mp3 key notes file

    c1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.key1); 
    c1.setOnClickListener(this);
    d1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.key2);
    d1.setOnClickListener(this);
    e1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.key3);
    e1.setOnClickListener(this);
    f1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.key4);
    f1.setOnClickListener(this);        
    g1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.key5);
    g1.setOnClickListener(this);
    a1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.key6);
    a1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.key7);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The OnClick method (the first if example works, of course, but if I want a complex instrument I'll have repeated code. So I want this "else" to be the only statement):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Button b = (Button)v;
    String note=b.getText().toString();

    if(v==c1){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c1);
        mp.start();
       }
      else{
        play( note+".mp3");
      }
```

And the attempt of the play method:

```
  public void play(String note){
  note.equals("cs2");//?? 

  //the mp3 files are stored in res/raw and I also tried that specific path     but it didnt work. The keys are silent, except the c1

 }
```

EDIT:
 Now I have only this:

```
    public void play(String note){
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,getResources().getIdentifier(note,"raw",getPackageName()));
      mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    clickCount++;
    updateClickCount();

    Button b = (Button)v;
    String note=b.getText().toString();
    play(note);
    }
```

But the app still crashes

EDIT: The XML

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.vtorferreira.sounds.MainActivity">



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vtorferreira.sounds.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="1200dp"
        android:id="@+id/kid"
        android:src="@drawable/kid"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="1200dp"
        android:id="@+id/partido"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="34"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#9BC53D"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key1_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#2660A4"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key2_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#399E5A"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key3_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#5F0F40"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key4_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black3"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#FA7921"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key5_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#9BC53D"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key6_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black5"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#2660A4"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key7_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#399E5A"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key8_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black6"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#5F0F40"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key9_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black7"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#FA7921"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key10_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black8"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#9BC53D"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key11_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#2660A4"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key12_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black9"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#399E5A"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key13_ext"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/black10"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#5F0F40"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key14_ext"/>









        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="7"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#2660A4"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#2660A4"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#399E5A"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key3"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#5F0F40"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#FA7921"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key5"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#9BC53D"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key6"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#2660A4"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key7"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#399E5A"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key8"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#5F0F40"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key9"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#FA7921"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key10"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#9BC53D"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key11"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#2660A4"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key12"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#399E5A"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key13"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="#5F0F40"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/key14"/>





        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/pontos"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="8"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:background="#2072CA"
                    android:id="@+id/pref"
                    android:text="Preferences"

                    />
                <ToggleButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:background="#2072CA"
                    android:id="@+id/solo"
                    android:textOff="Play Magic Piano!"
                    android:textOn="Close Piano"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:background="#2072CA"
                    android:id="@+id/learn"
                    android:text="Learn about piano"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


      </LinearLayout>

     </RelativeLayout>



   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's the error log now ?

Comment: it still points to the play(note) on the Onclick and to the mp=Mediaplayer etc in the method play

Comment: but what's the stacktrace... ? the error message that appears in your logs..

Comment: I just tried the code... it does work. the pb now might come from the button gettext...

Comment: In the play method, display a toast : Toast.makeText(this, (note, 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   Check that the filename is correct, extension shouldn't appear !

Comment: the toast doesnt appear, sorry, where i can find this debbuger?

Comment: Place the toast on first line (before the line that make app crash). For the debugger, find Android Monitor at the bottom of android studio then click on it then logcat tab. You then can filter by error

Comment: Anyway just check that text on button are written as they appear in raw folder. Case sensitive.

Comment: the log says:      android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 (at the mp line)

Comment: yes thay all are in lowercase

Comment: yep, are you sure the text on button is the exact name of a file in raw folder ?

Comment: this error means that i need a try catch?

Comment: you can place a Log, at the start of play method :  Log.e("button text", "button text is : " + note);

Comment: yep will need some ocnsolidation (making sure file do exists, or try catch. in the catch you could display the log i wrote before

Comment: i have all notes in the raw folder, but not all are declared as buttons, just seven...this is the problem i guess. To test it i have to leave just the 7 files?

Comment: i edited my answer. just check your log :)

Comment: nope as long as you click on a button which text is exactly the same as one in the raw folder (without extension)

Comment: The Log: E/Error: error playing file with name : 
         android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Comment: ok then the text on your button is empty... so it doesn't find any file with a blank name.

Comment: The text on each of your button should be a filename without extension !

Comment: Can you show your xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove file extension (+ ".mp3") and use :
`getResources().getIdentifier("FILE NAME WITHOUT EXTENSION","raw", getPackageName())`

Also make sure each of your button text is holding a filename present in your raw folder without extension. For exemple "c1".

Here is how should look final code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String note = b.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    play(note);
}

public void play(String note){
  try {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,getResources().getIdentifier(note,"raw", getPackageName()));
    mp.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("Error", "error playing file with name : " + note + "\n" + e);
  }

}
```

You must set text on your buttons elements. For each one, you should display a filename. for example adding `android:text"c1"` :

```
<Button
   android:text="c1"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="0.5"
   android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
   android:background="#2660A4"
   android:visibility="visible"
   android:id="@+id/key1"/>
```

To clarify a bit, the code retrieve the text on the button. for example 'c1'. Then, your app will try to find the file with name c1 in your raw folder. If you don't set any text on your buttons... Then of course, your app won't find any resource with name '' ! Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: thanks for the comment
the word note in here - openRawResource(note)); gets red underlined. It says: openRawResource(int)in Resources cannot be applied to
(java.lang.String)

Comment: with the edited answer the app crashes and the log points to your line :(

Comment: did you removed the + ".mp3"

Comment: edited answer. forcing note to be lowercase by adding `toLowerCase()`

Comment: nop, the log still says the same thing...like the file wasnt even there...i dont get it

Comment: Could you please post your xml file with your buttons element

Comment: FYI, here the log display the text that is present on the button (in your case none) you clicked which appear empty. Then it displays the error catched by the try catch.

Comment: Ok, found the problem... check my edited answer. now the button displaying c1 will work. do the same on your other button with the correct text !

Comment: Also added some extra information hoping you will understand how it does work.

Comment: yes, that makes sense...well its java :) I'll try if it works

Comment: Also i wonder why you set your button visibility to invisible but that's another thing ;)

Comment: It worked!! Thanks Anto! Well, that's the nature of the program, the keys appear when you click a toggle button...:)

Comment: Good to hear, hope you understood the logic ;)

Comment: yes i did, quite simple when someone explains it well, thanks man ;)